# Whats is the difference between nested method call and delegates?

Tags: c#, function, c#-4.0, delegates

consider following:

**1st APPROACH:**

```
public void f3()
{
f2();
f1();
}
```

and this ...

**2nd APPROACH:**

```
    class Sample
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate(string s);
    MyDelegate obj;

    public Sample()
    {
        obj += new MyDelegate(input);
        obj+=new MyDelegate(something);
        obj += new MyDelegate(someStaticMethod);
    }
}
```

When i call f3()  it will call the functions listed inside it ... same would happen when i will invoke a delegate ... so whats the use of delegate to handle some event when i can use 1st approach ... **the 1st approach too encapsulates the method call..**

Comment: If you use a delegate, you can *delegate work* to someone else. Your users can now provide a custom implementation instead of being hard coded to whatever function is there.

Comment: except for usage ... both ways are similar? i mean the way methods would invoke are same.. ryt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of the delegate, the invocation order of the attached functions is not specified.

Also, you can attach any number of functions to it, even during runtime, from other objects, not just the hard coded ones as in the first approach. The delegate has wider usage.

Comment: In addition, the stack trace should be easier to read when debugging.

Comment: +1 This is a pretty good answer. I'd also want to mention that a delegate is a reference to a method.  You only need to know the signature at compile time, whereas in the OP 1st approach, you would need to know exactly which methods to call.

Comment: If you have functions which *must* run in a specified order, then the first approach is the correct one. Otherwise they're conceptually the same, but the second is more flexible in what it can do.

Comment: Mike Bantegui: would the 1st approach also cause stack overflow exception if too many methods are added to it .. while delegates would never do that right??

Comment: @Sana.91 if you've added enough method calls to get a stack overflow, you should probably not add that many method calls or upgrade your dev box. Usually, stack overflows mean there is something really wrong.

Comment: @JimSchubert: i wont need to know that for 1st approach either .. .. i would just call f3() .. right? ... both approaches can be used a wrapper ..?

Comment: @Sana.91 Yes, if you're calling a method within the same class.  Delegates support binding multiple invocations to a single delegate ([example](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html)). They also support variance [see this post for examples](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2009/08/29/understanding-csharp-covariance-and-contravariance-1-delegates.aspx).  Delegates are way more powerful than direct method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

First approach is static.  Delegate approach allows you or a caller to determine what gets called at a later time.

Comment: I'd be careful with the word *static* so as not to confuse it with the keyword `static`. :p