# Delegate execution in Unity3d using c#

Tags: asynchronous, interface, delegates, unity-game-engine

I have callbacks implements in my unity3d game in such a way that they are all nested,i.e. one callback leads to another call, whose callback leads to another call and so on upto 5 times. But the last two callbacks are losing their order. Before the second last delegate finishes execution, the last one gets executed! I am using delegates as means of message transfer (other way could be to implement interfaces). Do delegates in C# behave asynchronously by any chance? Implementin callbacks using delegates and using interfaces should yield the same results everytime, correct? And both are synchronous? Any lead on the issue would be greatly helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Do you register them at one instance member like  `myEvent += myCallback1;`  `myEvent += myCallback2;`  and so on?

Comment: Can you post a code fragment where we can see how you nest your delegates?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're using delegates the invocation order could not be specified.
See: [Whats is the difference between nested method call and delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226584/whats-is-the-difference-between-nested-method-call-and-delegates)